# MYSQL performance issue - 1 table with one row vs 1 table with many rows

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a doubt regarding how to store data inside MYSQL tables.

Let's say I write 10k posts, 400 words each.

Is it better to store each post (the 400 words) in one row?
Or to split it into, let's say 10 rows (40 words each)?
Or to split into 100 rows (4 words each)?

Which structure will give me the best performance, less weight, better loading time, etc..?
What is more important - how many rows you have (1 or 10 or 100) or how much data is inside your rows (400 or 40 or 4)?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_paralysis

Comment: what do you mean by that? Is it not important to think about it if you have 10k posts?

Comment: Do not split up things that belong together.

Comment: the question is if it's helping with performance... I will not split if everybody say that it's not worth it and it's convincing, but I am asking about the performance side of it. What is better? to have smaller rows but many or larger rows but few?

Comment: *Premature optimization is the root of all evil*.

Comment: I totally agree about that, but I am just wondering how it's the best for performance. I am seeing the answer slowly and it's what I thought before, but now it's clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More rows can make it slower to query. In addition to this the complexity you will add by splitting posts up is not worth it. The amount of time it will take for new developers to work out what's going  on is increased and the more complex code is more likely to have errors in it, either now or in the future.

Put each post in a row, profile it and then change that if you find you are having performance problems.

Comment: But let's say I don't have a problem with splitting a post, will it give me better performance? Because maybe it won't and then I have no problem, I go by the normal way. But if it does, I want to know. Think of a 10k posts site

Comment: @tomastsc do you have a problem with performance? if not, don't engineer a solution to a non-existant problem

Comment: I had in the past but now I am not running this site anymore. I still want to know the answer in order to solve it next time, on my next project.

Comment: @tomastsc I can't see adding more rows speeding up your queries. Especially if you are filtering them.

Comment: can you make your comment more detailed so I understand what you mean? if you are saying it is not worth it, I want to know why. Many thanks!

Comment: @tomastsc It is not worth it as it will not give you a performance increase and it will make the code more complex needlessly.

Comment: the amount of rows in a table do not have impact on weight, indexing, search, speed? the same question about the amount of data per row. Many thanks for yor answer @jamesj

Answer (score 0):

There is no definitive answer to your question.

Given the task of storing messages/posts in a database, I'd assume most people would start by designing the table to store one message per row. Maybe after doing some analysis on the data to be stored would the decision be made to split each message into a number of pages with each page taking up 400 words. Without this analysis you have no problem to solve.

To be honest, you'd be best doing a bit of your own research on the subject. Read up on the theory behind relational databases. Have a go at making a simple system that would create and load posts that were split into multiple pages.